# Remove trailing zeros in decimal value with changing length

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure I am doing that displays odds but the client wants only significant digits to be shown.  So, 1.50 would show as '1.5' and 1.00 would show as '1'.

How can I get MySQL to not display trailing zeros;

i.e. in the database:

> *Odds* 
>   1.500 
>   23.030 
>   2.000
>   4.450

would display as

> 1.5
>   23.03
>   2
>   4.45

Thanks for any help

Answer (score -19, accepted):

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM yourodds)
FROM ...
```

Docs for the [TRIM function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that numbers like "150" would be corrupted, turning into 15?

Comment: Pretty much. but you can't expect much intelligence from a simple string operation. You could look for `.` chars and only trim 0's that follow one, but then it's not a simple operation anymore.

Comment: Aside from missing some cases, I think that this ultimately reinvents what MySQL will do with its built-in string to numeric type-casting functionality.

Comment: it yields "3." for "3.0" and "3" for "30".

Comment: This should NOT be the accepted answer as it's wrong and horrible and dangerous. The only correct answer is the one by Christopher McGowan

Comment: I get the same problem as @flaschenpost, Hariboo's answer below is the correct one.

Comment: I tried this `SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM 1519494844.000000)` result is `1519494844.`, this is wrong

Answer (score 88):

Easiest way by far, just add zero!

Examples:

```
SET 
    @yournumber1="1.500", 
    @yournumber2="23.030",
    @yournumber3="2.000",
    @yournumber4="4.450"
;

SELECT 
    (@yournumber1+0),
    (@yournumber2+0),
    (@yournumber3+0),
    (@yournumber4+0)
;

+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| (@yournumber1+0) | (@yournumber2+0) | (@yournumber3+0) | (@yournumber4+0) |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|              1.5 |            23.03 |                2 |             4.45 |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If the column your value comes from is `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC` type, then cast it to string first to make sure the conversion takes place...ex:

```
SELECT (CAST(`column_name` AS CHAR)+0) FROM `table_name`;
```

For a shorter way, just use any built-in string function to do the cast:

```
SELECT TRIM(`column_name`)+0 FROM `table_name`;
```

Comment: this one `SELECT TRIM(\`column_name\`)+0 FROM \`table_name\`;` helped me out.

Comment: I should also add, if precision is desired, can use a math operation that implicitly casts to numeric.

Comment: The fact that the output type is a double actually causes problems too. 79228162514264337593543950335.000 becomes 7.922816251426434e28

Comment: This does not work within CONCAT:
`SELECT CONCAT(SUM(titels)+0, ' titels') FROM fact_data_uitg_factuurKosten`

Will render `5.0 titels`.

Comment: @Roemer, see the part about converting values that are numeric types already into string before adding zero

Comment: That's a good call, @Jannes, there is a limit of digits beyond which the library will switch to exponential notation instead, which may or may not be desirable :-(.

Comment: The 'easiest' would be just to [cast the value as `DOUBLE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64507815/244297).

Comment: In my case adding 0 did not work, so I've tried 0E0 as mentioned in one of the other replies, and it did work.
Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 43):

**EDIT**: I would use the answer below by Christopher McGowan instead - adding 0 to the value, which is better, instead.

---

It's important to check there is actually a decimal point if doing trimming.

So I think you'd want to use:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '0' from yourfield)) AS yourfield
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourfield LIKE '%.%'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use `FLOOR()`?

Comment: For 23.030, for instance, FLOOR() would return 23 rather than 23.03.

Comment: Horribly convulated and messes with an existing query. At least do something like  `IF(yourfield LIKE '%.%', blabla, yourfield) AS yourfield` and don't mess with the `WHERE` clause. Anyway, the really correct answer is by Christopher McGowan.

Answer (score 13):

this worked for me..  round the field to 2 decimal places and then trim any trailing zeros

So that 2.10 is 2.1

```
SELECT trim(round(FIELDNAME,2))+0 
FROM tbl_name
....
```

Comment: This will work just fine without the round function.

Comment: This is the one that works. `SELECT TRIM(ROUND(3/5,3))+0` works, `SELECT ROUND(3/5,3)+0` does not.

Comment: kojow: but then you can have endless digits behind the decimal point. For reporting, you mostly won't want that.

Answer (score 6):

To remove trailing zeros from a `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC` or string type column, you can simply cast the value to `DOUBLE`, e.g.:

```
SELECT CAST(mycol AS DOUBLE) from mytable;
```

or

```
SELECT mycol + 0E0 FROM mytable;
```

In fact, the "cast to char and add zero" trick mentioned in other answers does the same, but in a more indirect (and likely less efficient) way, e.g:

```
SELECT CAST(mycol AS CHAR)+0 FROM mytable; -- converts to string, then to number
SELECT TRIM(mycol)+0 FROM mytable; -- ditto
```

Comment: Casting to `DOUBLE` worked beautifully until I moved from MariaDB away to MySQL 5.7: `You have an error in your SQL syntax [...] near 'DOUBLE`. I could cry.

Comment: @Anse Does `SELECT mycol + 0E0 FROM mytable` work? [Casting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to `DOUBLE` seems to require MySQL 8.0.17.

Comment: Indeed, `mycol + 0E0` works on MySQL 5.7 and strips trailing decimal zeros. Interesting, as 0E0 is just the scientific notation of 0, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Please use below function , it will take care of number having zero without decimal places i.e 150 etc....

```
 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
 SET character_set_client = utf8;
 DELIMITER $$
 USE `mydbname`$$

 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `FN_STRIP_TRAILING_ZER0`$$

 CREATE DEFINER=`mydbuser`@`%` FUNCTION `FN_STRIP_TRAILING_ZER0`(tNumber DECIMAL(10,7)) RETURNS VARCHAR(20) CHARSET utf8

 BEGIN
     DECLARE strBuff VARCHAR(20);
     DECLARE cnt  NUMERIC(2);
     DECLARE tString VARCHAR(20);
     SELECT CAST(tNumber AS CHAR) INTO tString;
     SELECT LOCATE('.',tString) INTO cnt;
     IF cnt > 0 THEN
       SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM tString)) INTO strBuff;   
     ELSE
       SET strBuff = tString;
     END IF;
     RETURN strBuff;
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

## Addendum:

Typically to call this would involve:
     SELECT FN_STRIP_TRAILING_ZER0(1.5);

Comment: Isn't this is a very complex reinvention of what MySQL can do with its built-in string to numeric type casting logic?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found is to cast your round value to FLOAT:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(1.2345984372, 2) AS FLOAT)
```

Comment: while this may be an accurate answer to the question, please be aware that this is a very old question, asked and answered 4 years ago.  Very old answers like this should take extra care to demonstrate how the new answer is relevant to people searching and finding this question relating to a problem they are having.

Comment: AS FLOAT gave an error, but AS DOUBLE worked for me. +0 didn't, so this for me is the one that works.
https://i.ibb.co/SvkG1Zc/cast.png

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me:

**SINGLE COLUMN:**

```
SELECT TRIM(column_name)+0 AS column_name FROM table_name;
```

**MULTIPLE COLUMNS:**

```
SELECT 
TRIM(column1)+0 AS column1,
TRIM(column2)+0 AS column2,   
TRIM(column3)+0 AS column3,
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: This worked on a `DECIMAL (8,4)` column, while `CAST (mycol AS DOUBLE)` gave a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Taking forward the answer provided by @fooquency, if the column is already declared as a DECIMAL with a non-zero value for D in DECIMAL(M, D), we do not need to perform the WHERE condition

```
WHERE yourfield LIKE '%.%'
```

as the values in the column will always contain D digits after the decimal dot (.)

Comment: Note: This kind of formatting does not seem to be very precise in summation, with a lot digits after the decimal dot. For instance, dont use "SELECT SUM(TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '0' from yourfield)))" in very high precision requirements (precision implying digits after the decimal dot).

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROUND` or `CEILING`, in the query you just have to type:

```
SELECT ROUND(2/50)
```

or

```
SELECT CEILING(2/50)
```

Comment: But then you lose precision.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a situation where I could not modify the code nor the SQL query, but I was allowed to modify the database structure. So I changed the column format from `DECIMAL` to `FLOAT` and it solved my problem.

Comment: Commented on this before but that could be a dangerous change. DECIMAL type is used for exact values. FLOAT type is for approximate values.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PHP as the scripting language you may use the following:

```
$var = (float)$var_having_extra_0; // $var = (float) 17.5000
```

Or use the PHP `floatval` function:

```
$var = floatval($var_having_extra_0); // $var = floatval(17.5000)
```

Comment: PHP is not included in question tags

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '0' from yourfield)) AS yourfield
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourfield LIKE '%.%'
```

or

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '0' from yourfield)) AS yourfield
FROM yourtable
WHERE instr(yourfield,'.') != 0
```

work ok but require a "where" clause.

I think the best solution is probably:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM ROUND(yourfield,3))) 
FROM yourtable
```

as it doesn't require a "where" clause, doesn't require any special code, 
and also lets you set the maximum precision of the number upfront.

Answer (score -2):

Taking fragments of the others answers in this page I came to this conclusion:

```
SELECT ( IF(
    myfield LIKE '%.%', 
    TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM myfield)),
    myfield
) ) FROM mytable
```

Cheers