# Is it possible to search for a value, optionally looking at the trailing 0's in decimal values

Tags: mysql

So what I'm after is searching for "1.00" needs to find matches on 1, 1.0, 1.00, 1.000, 11, 11.00, etc

So what I'm after is a simple search, but with the trailing decimal places are optional, as they may or may not be  added by the users to the database.

Currently I have this, which obviously won't do the trick

```
SELECT * 
FROM `prices` 
WHERE `price` = '%1.00';
```

Doing the following will work, but I'd like something more concise, as the

```
SELECT * 
FROM `prices` 
WHERE `price` = '1.00'
OR `price` = '1.0'
OR `price` = '1'; 
# NOTE THE LACK OF DECIMAL PLACE
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're really trying to do is to compare these strings as numbers, right? If that's true, then convert `price` to a number using addition.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `prices`
WHERE (0 + `price`) = 1;
```

If it's a decimal, you could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `prices`
WHERE ROUND( 0 + `price` , 2 ) = 0.99;
```

Comment: While it's a valid response (hence the upvote) I'm unable to generate that SQL with the engine we have, as I can't modify the columns in the where clause to be anything but column => value

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can achieve this using the TRIM() function, as in

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM `price`) as trimmed
FROM `prices`
WHERE trimmed = '1'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7968606/1613391

Comment: Actually, since floats automatically strip trailing 0's when they save to the database, I'll never have the case where a value is stored as 1.0 at all, so I simply need to modify the value I'm comparing against to strip the trailing 0's, so it's more a PHP task from here on.