# MySQL Remove decimal point (.00) and keep decimal points if not .00

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to remove the decimal points if value has .00 and keep the decimal points if not .00 using MySQL query itself.

For eg: 
If the datas are 2.56 and 3.00 then the mysql query should return 2.56 & 3

Comment: already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968531/remove-trailing-zeros-in-decimal-value-with-changing-length you want the SQL function TRIM

Comment: I wan to do it with mysql chris

Comment: Are you dealing with strings? MySql returns numbers already trimmed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/26341

Comment: I am dealing with decimal

Comment: Well, [according to this test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/26341), you don't need to worry about it, it already does what you want.

Comment: @mickmackusa `1.5` and `1.50` have the same value. My comment was bad though in that it would trim `1000` to `1`, which is vastly different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT

I wonder if you're actually after something slightly different. So:

```
SET @n = 17.00;
SELECT @n, TRIM(TRAILING '.00' FROM CAST(@n AS CHAR)) AS a;
SET @n = 17.30;
SELECT @n, TRIM(TRAILING '.00' FROM CAST(@n AS CHAR)) AS b;
SET @n = 17.32;
SELECT @n, TRIM(TRAILING '.00' FROM CAST(@n AS CHAR)) AS c;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/26367'

```
17      17
17.3    17.30
17.32   17.32
```

The difference here is that if there is no decimal, return the whole number, other return what is there (with trailing zeros).

---

Note, values that are already [native floats in MySql are already trimmed](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/26341), so I'm supposing these are strings.

```
SELECT
   '17.00' * 1 AS a
 , '17.32' * 1 AS b
 , '17.30' * 1 AS c
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/26343

Produces:

```
a   b      c
----------------
17  17.32  17.3
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could use sqlfiddle without a schema.

Comment: Thanks @Jared your edit worked out.
This was what I needed 
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.00' FROM `price`) from products