# need function in SQL to help me to get a part of the number

Tags: mysql, sql

I had in my records numbers in my database like that ( 5243700.0000000000 ) and I need the function in my Query that help me to remove some zeros from this number to be like this (5243700.00) only 2 zeros after ,

Comment: Check [Mathematical Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html) or [String Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) it should be in there somewhere..

Comment: How is that number stored? VARCHAR? DECIMAL? FLOAT?

Comment: that number stored as a DECIMAL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove trailing zeros in decimal value with changing length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968531/remove-trailing-zeros-in-decimal-value-with-changing-length)

Comment: FORMAT(Round(ph_totalprice,2), 'N2')

Comment: solved by this (FORMAT(Round(ph_totalprice,2), 'N2') ) thanks all for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use  [`ROUND()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_round.asp) function with precision `2`

```
SET @nr = 5243700.0000000000;
SELECT ROUND(@nr,2) as "Rounded Value";

 Rounded Value
+--------------+
|  5243700.00  |
+--------------+
```

Comment: Dear Barbaros , Be informed that records into column (Total_price) that contain  more than 1000 record so how to use this function with that column not only one a specific record to be affected on all records in that column

Comment: Hi dear @TonyMedhat this assignment to a variable is just a demonstration, you can include `ROUND()` function within your SELECT statement no matter how many records return from that.

Comment: 9264300.0000000000
9264300.0000000000
9651000.0000000000
12799800.0000000000
13204600.0000000000
2132100.0000000000
2204550.0000000000
2204550.0000000000
2132100.0000000000
1164375.0000000000

Comment: After Wrote the Query Select Round(ph_totalprice,2) from ph_phdunit  still there is no effect 9264300.0000000000 9264300.0000000000 9651000.0000000000 12799800.0000000000 13204600.0000000000 2132100.0000000000 2204550.0000000000 2204550.0000000000 2132100.0000000000 1164375.0000000000

Answer (score 0):

select cast(your_float_column as decimal(10,2))
from your_table