# SQL: How to remove the zeros after decimal point in some columns of a table

Tags: sql, mysql, integer

There is a table queried by sql as below.
In some columns, there are too many zeros after decimal point of the number. How to modify the current sql query so that it shows the desired table?
Thank you!

select Name, amount, Number_of_products
from Table1

| Name | amount | Number_of_products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10.0000000 | 1.00000000000 |
| B | 123.0000000000 | 3.00000000000 |

I want to have such table

| Name | amount | Number_of_products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 |
| B | 123 | 3 |

How should I update the sql query?
Thank you

Comment: Can the number of products ever be a decimal value? If not, it would be better to change the data type of that column rather than casting it in a query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove trailing zeros in decimal value with changing length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968531/remove-trailing-zeros-in-decimal-value-with-changing-length)

Comment: Add complete `SHOW CREATE TABLE Table1;` output into your question. *How should I update the sql query?* Adjust output format in your client simply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAST` or `ROUND`.

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    CAST(amount AS INT) AS amount,
    CAST(Number_of_products AS INT) AS Number_of_products
FROM Table1
```

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    ROUND(amount, 0) AS amount,
    ROUND(Number_of_products, 0) AS Number_of_products
FROM Table1
```

Change `INT` to what you expect as outcome data type `BIGINT`, `SMALLINT` etc.

Comment: This will for example return 12 for 12.34 which is likely not intended.

Comment: Yes you are right, this will only work for given input.